# Gradle transitive module dependencies: 'implementation' not working, but 'compile' does

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a pretty straightforward gradle project with `app`, `service` and `lib` modules.

`app` depends on `service`

`service` depends on `lib`

When I try to use class from `lib` in `app`, it won't work, if I depend on services like following:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':service')
}
```

But if I do:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':service')
}
```

it works just fine.

Thing is, the latter makes the script obsolete, won't work in latest Gradle.

**What am I missing?** `implementation` seems to be a direct replacement of `compile` to me, but doesn't work.

IntelliJ, Gradle (6.9), Java8.
`settings.gradle` include all modules, all have `java` plugin specified.

Answer (score 0):

Bruh, it's not the same.

Use `api` instead of `implementation` to expose transitives from the `service` module.

And add `java-library` plugin to have `api` in the this `build.gradle` file

Be careful with doing so, though, it's not always good to expose dependencies, modules are modules for a reason.